# How can I fadein/slidedown a textarea if a checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery, input, textarea

I want to output a textarea based on a checkbox. I would like it to fadeIn or Slidedown, beneath the checkbox.

I have a checkbox controlling a input field with JS, like so:

```
function enable_text(status) {
    status = (status) ? false : true; //convert status boolean to text 'disabled'
    document.password.myFormName.disabled = status;
    }
```

Can this be done with jQuery for both input and textareas if checked? Which areas of jQuery API should I research?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with the `slideToggle()`

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvMZT/)

Comment: Perfect. How do I do it the other way around? If checked, it slideToggle();'s

Comment: You could test it with giving a param into the slidetoggle

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('input.anycheckbox').live('click', function(){
    $('textarea.txt').slideToggle();
  });
});
```